# How to pass a method to another method that accepts Func?

Tags: c#

I've this method:

```
RateLimiter.Perform(Func<Task> perform)
```

and I want to perform this method:

```
await PassMessageAsync(message, id, name)
```

It shows no error, just to make sure, is this the correct way?:

```
await RateLimiter.Perform(async () => { await PassMessageAsync(message, id, name);});
```

---

**Update:**

The idea is to limit number of concurrent methods.

```
public async Task<T> Perform<T>(Func<Task<T>> perform, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    using (await _AwaitableConstraint.WaitForReadiness(cancellationToken)) 
    {
        return await perform();
    }
}
```

How can I change the signature to accept any method with any much parameters, and await it?

Comment: using `delegate`?

Comment: You're currently not passing the method itself but are creating another method(the lambda expression method) which invokes the passmesssagemethod.

Comment: @Hristo The method itself cannot be passed due to its need for a closure on `message`, `id` and `name` (plus it doesn't match the signature for `Func<Task>`).

Comment: @serpent5 yes, that is true but in that case it is up to the author to define what is the 'correct way'

Comment: @serpent5 Thanks, I've updated the question, please check it

Comment: @hristo please check the updated question

Comment: Are you asking how to change the signature of `Perform()` to accept a function with any parameters? How are you going to call this function? You aren't passing any arguments to `perform()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there have been no answers at all so far, I will attempt to answer your specific questions. Regarding:

```
await RateLimiter.Perform(async () => { await PassMessageAsync(message, id, name);});
```

> It shows no error, just to make sure, is this the correct way?:

That will work, but the lambda does not need to be `async`. You simply need to pass in something that can be awaited, e.g. `Task`/`Task<T>`:

```
await RateLimiter.Perform(() => PassMessageAsync(message, id, name));
```

By doing this you are making your code cleaner and eliminating an extra `await`.

> How can I change the signature to accept any method with any much
>   parameters, and await it?

You could probably manage this with dynamics or some such loose typing, but I wouldn't. What you *can* do is change what you are passing in to match the signature you have. As it happens, that is precisely what you have done in creating a lambda statement.

So how does that answer your question? Well, assuming that we are only interested in passing methods that return `Task` or `Task<T>` to `Perform`, you will need two methods: one for each. You already have a function for `Task<T>`. The function for `Task` will look like this:

```
public async Task Perform(Func<Task> perform, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  using (await _AwaitableConstraint.WaitForReadiness(cancellationToken))
  {
    await perform();
  }
}
```

These two methods should be all you need.